# HTA to EXE but current working folder changes to temp. Solution?

Tags: directory, exe, hta, temp

I need some help with the appropriate coding to prevent the newly formed EXE from using the TEMP folder as the current working folder.

Using the HTA (no conversion) in any folder works fine and the correct CWD is used.

```
    Set Sh=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    cwd=Sh.CurrentDirectory
```

Converting to an EXE the program uses the following folder instead of the folder path its being executed in.

file:///C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/%7B3479C69C-F8A7-4FE0-9903-68266AAF2EA7%7D/test.hta

As I understand it, the converted EXE gets "unpacked" into the temp folder and is run there until it closes, then it automatically deletes itself from temp.

So how do I prevent the EXE from using the temp folder as the CWD instead of the actual folder it is executed in?

Do I need to put in extra code for the user to navigate and select the actual CWD? That seems counter-productive! I would really like a piece of code to read from the actual (true) path of the EXE.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What tool do you use to convert the script? I use "VBS To EXE" and the current directory always worked well.

I just tested it with your two lines and it worked (I added `msgbox cwd` and the path was right).

Comment: You use a program called "VBS to EXE" to convert HTA files?
Can you please explain more about this program, download site etc. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried VBS to EXE and it doesnt work for HTA files.

Comment: I have also used the `msgbox cwd` multiple times throughout the code, from start to finish to test when it changes, but it doesn't.
Its only when you try and click a button on the page that it no longer uses the original cwd. it changes to the TEMP folder.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't work with HTA. I just found a tool called VbsEdit. I tried it and it worked with the current directory. I did reproduced the probleme with another tool but this one should work (avoid HTA to EXE)

Comment: Yes VbsEdit is the tool I used originally to create the exe file. Although it doesnt have many controls, just the very basics - no control for .ico for example. I did correct my code to allow the exe to run in any folder and use that folder as the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think the 32bit version of vbsedit will also have troubles. Make sure to use the 64bit version.